# Error during import schema to another schema in Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I can't solve problem during run my application, and can't find answer for it.
When I run my code I get the next error:

`pydantic.errors.PydanticUndefinedAnnotation: name 'PostWithoutUserSchema' is not defined`

My schemas are in one directory `schemas`. Next code from `schemas/user.py`:

```
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .post import PostWithoutUserSchema


class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        from_attributes=True
    )


class UserWithPostSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str

    posts: list['PostWithoutUserSchema'] = []
```

And `schemas/post.py`:

```
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .user import UserSchema


class PostSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str

    user: UserSchema

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        from_attributes=True
    )


class PostWithoutUserSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
```

Version:

python = 3.11.4

fastapi = 0.109.2

pydantic = 2.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer that solved my problem.
I only need to make right query for selecting of post with user using `joinedload` in router.